# Extract zip file with swedish ÅÄÖ in the filenames in python2.7

Tags: python-2.7

When I extract my zip file containing a file with Å, Ä or Ö letters, 
I get garbage characters.
Im using python 2.7.

```
with zipfile.ZipFile(temp_zip_path.decode('utf-8')) as f:
    for fn in f.namelist():
        extracted_path = f.extract(fn)
```

Comment: you get garbage characters where/when? i.e. when print extracted_path, extract zip, etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zipfile assumes that the encoding of the filenames is CP437. If your zipfile encoding is not unicode, you need to decode file/directory names if they contain accented letters in order to see the non-garbaged name. But if you try to extract contents based on the decoded string, it won't be found, because zipfile will find stuff by the original (garbage or not) name.

You could rename the files one by one after extracting but that would be painful.

What you could do is something like this: read the contents and write them on the decoded name.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import zipfile
import os

temp_zip_path = r'd:\Python_projects\sandbox\cp_437.zip'
temp_zip_path2 = r'd:\Python_projects\sandbox\unicode.zip'
target_loc = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))


def unpack_cp437_or_unicode(archive_path):
    with zipfile.ZipFile(archive_path) as zz:
        for zipped_name in zz.namelist():
            try:
                real_name = zipped_name.decode('cp437')
            except UnicodeEncodeError:
                real_name = zipped_name

            with zz.open(zipped_name) as archived:
                contents = archived.read()
            if zipped_name.endswith('/'):
                dirname = os.path.join(target_loc, real_name)
                if not os.path.isdir(dirname):
                    os.makedirs(dirname)
            else:
                with open(os.path.join(target_loc, real_name), 'wb') as target:
                    target.write(contents)


unpack_cp437_or_unicode(temp_zip_path)
unpack_cp437_or_unicode(temp_zip_path2)
```